# CSS Columns not working in Safari Mac

Tags: html, css, safari

On this site: getinjuryanswers.com, I added CSS columns. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but the content doesn't show up in Safari on Mac. Any ideas why?

HTML:

```
<div class="twocolumns col-md-12">
<p class="representation-text">
<p class="representation-text">Many cases settle out of court, you therefore need an effective negotiator on your side. Attorney Curtis Quay spent several years defending insurance companies against personal injury claims. He understands how they think and the games they play to deny you compensation. This gives you the upper hand during the negotiation process.</p>
<p class="representation-text">To recover for a personal injury case, you must prove the defendant was responsible for your harm. ITL has a strong network of investigators and professionals in San Diego to help build your case and get you the proper compensation. Proving damages can be complicated, but our lawyers have a proven track record of excellent results.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.twocolumns {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    /*column-count: 2;*/
    -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
    -moz-column-gap: 30px;
    /*column-gap: 30px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Safari < 9.0 does not support `column-gap`. Here is a work around that should achieve the same effect. Since your already using two separate elements to split content.

```
.twocolumns {
 width: 100%;
}
.twocolumns .representation-text {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.twocolumns .representation-text:last-child {
 width: calc(50% - 30px);
 margin-left: 30px;
}
```

You might also want to remove the empty `<p class="representation-text">`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried that, but it doesn't look right. Can you please take a look and let me know what I can do to fix the spacing issues? getinjuryanswers.com